# How to use multilingual in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to create multilingual app in Windows Phone 7. I am doing it from the help of one example but it is not giving me perfect solution. This is the [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wphowto/thread/6932dc75-5763-477e-abd4-1701c2df7909/).

Comment: What is your problem with the solution mentioned in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) gives you a good description on how to go about it. Also, check the [best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967552%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). 

For my own app i used [this guide](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Localizing-a-Windows-Phone-app-Step-by-Step). Goodluck!

After following that guide, you can use your localized strings in a listpicker (as requested in your comment):

```
 <toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Path=AppResources.ListPickerOption1, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
                    <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Path=AppResources.ListPickerOption2, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
                    <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Path=AppResources.ListPickerOption3, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
  </toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
```

Comment: But i want it to implement in my app like:- I have a Listpicker in this three languages is there English, Dari, Pastho if i will select dari then in my app for all the controls text should change in dari language and same for other language. I can't change always from device setting.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the following link:

[Windows Phone Localization](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-8-Localization.aspx)

And you can set the Culture in your code too:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```